# Can I cancel my teleport command?

Tags: diablo-iii

Sometimes I will accidentally hit T while playing Diablo III (oftentimes when I'm trying to type a chat without hitting Enter first). Is there a way to cancel myself from teleporting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving is the simplest way to stop it.

Simply click to move anywhere, and you'll break the channel.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Never thought to try that.